# How to alter Hive table based on insert statment?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I have declared a table as:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employee 
(primaryKey String, Firstname String, lastName String)" + " ROW FORMAT DELIMITED"
      + " FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\\t'"<br/>
      + " LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'"<br/>
      + " STORED AS TEXTFILE"
```

The table Employee has 3 columns. I want to alter the table if a fourth value i.e address is inserted. I am inserting the values based on another table.The following is my query.

```
"INSERT INTO TABLE Employee select primaryKey,Firstname,lastName from oldEmpTable"
```

This query is working. If I run the following query hive does not complain nor there is any change in the table. By the way I am using Spark.

```
"INSERT INTO TABLE Employee select primaryKey,Firstname,lastName,address from oldEmpTable"
```

Is there way I can alter the table based on Insert?

Comment: Are you expecting the Employee table to change its schema?

Comment: @mattinbits Yes  It should change

Answer (score 0):

The table schema is set with the `CREATE TABLE` command. The use of `INSERT INTO` with the additional field will not change the schema. You should either recreate the table, or use `ALTER TABLE` in order to change the schema, before doing the `INSERT` with the extra field.